# how to make a web browser grid responsive c# windows forms

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

i have been tasked to make a layout of 4 web browsers, that later could be used for security cameras.

the web browser part was easy, but i have been stuck at making it responsive, because when you run it and maximize the program, the resolution of the web browsers stay the same. and since this program will be running on a big flat screen it has to respond to the resolution.

i have looked all over the internet and have not found a solution. i have tried the anchoring but when i do this and i enlarge the program the browsers start over lapping each other. i have tried putting them in a flow grid and a table grid. other things i found was "this.AutoSize = true;" but i am kinda new to c# forms and do not understand this.

can anyone help?

the code and a few photo's of what happens
[how it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng7kc.png)

[what happens when enlarged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quXIf.png)

the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace webspace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("www.nos.nl");
            webBrowser2.Navigate("www.google.com");
            webBrowser3.Navigate("www.facebook.com");
            webBrowser4.Navigate("www.google.com/maps");
            this.AutoSize = true;
            
        }
        private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + "is loading...";
        }

        private void webBrowser2_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + "is loading...";
        }

        private void webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + "is loading...";
        }

        private void webBrowser4_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + "is loading...";
        }

        private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a layout that is two `Orientation=Horizontal` [SplitContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.orientation?view=netcore-3.1)s, inside another SplitContainer that is `Orientation=Vertical` (or vice versa, two verticals one on either side of a horizontal)

When the form resizes, set all the SplitContainer's SplitterDistances to 50% of the width/height as appropriate.. Unless the user's customised them (in which case decide what to do, like have a proportional resize, thereby allowing the user to have some views bigger than others)

Make the web browser controls Dock=Fill their panels

### [image]

Note that the WebBrowser control is quite old now, and should probably be replaced with a WebView2 (Chrome-based Edge)